# Can I express “everything that the job is about” with “à propos de”?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions

Take the following sentence as an example:

> Si vous êtes à la recherche d'une personne qui s'intéresse beaucoup à **tout le poste est à propos de**, je vous prie de…

I'm trying to figure out how to fit it into the expression, whose English counterpart would be:

> If you are in search of a person who is very interested in **everything that the job is about**, I ask you to…

There is probably a simpler way to say it. I am hesitant to say the following works, using *y* and *en* to replace *à* and *de* in the expression, but I'm not sure:

> Si vous êtes à la recherche d'une personne qui s'intéresse beaucoup à **tout y en propos le poste**, je vous prie de…

So my question is: how can I properly use "à propos de" in the context here? Or, does the second phrase (French) actually have the correct meaning?

Comment: Il semblerait qu'il ait une erreur quelque part, un francophone *n'y reconnait pas ses petits* (la phrase est incompréhensible). Cela ressemble à un courriel expédié sans être relu.

Comment: @cl-r Ce n’est pas limpide en première lecture, mais la phrase française est de sa création. Il cherche à traduire de l’anglais vers le français, pas à comprendre la phrase française.

Comment: Oui, exactement. Je n'ai pas eu le temps ce matin de l'écrire en français, ni de bien rechercher comment utiliser l'expression. Bref, je comprends mieux maintenant - j'ai eu du mal à essayer de trouver un synonyme aussi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

“About” by itself can sometimes be translated as “*à propos*”; “to be about”, however, is translated as “*concerner*”. Thus, neither or your sentences is french.

For your translation, I would write: “*Si vous recherchez quelqu’un qui s’intéresse à tous les aspects du poste, […]*” and avoid “*concerner*” altogether.

Answer (score 1):

« À propos »  ne convient pas ici pour rendre le *about* (this job is about...)

---

I don't see how you could use *"à propos de"* to translate "about" here. *This job is about...* could be translated by : « Ce travail consiste en ... »
 and you could have something like:

"Si vous êtes à la recherche d'une personne qui s’intéresse à ce en quoi consiste ce poste..."
which is correct but not a very good turn of phrase.

I'd rather go for something like:
" Si vous êtes à la recherche d'une personne qui s’intéresse à la description ce poste..."

(By the way if you want to use *consister*, then it's *"consister en + noun"* or *"consiter à + verb"*.)

Answer (score 1):

*en tout ce qui concerne ce poste*